# Prevent copying Site Templates

Tags: css

How can Prevent copying my Site templates such as CSS & Javascript code or anyone fails to copy my website.
please help me.

I tried many ways but it was inconclusive.I'm sorry that asked this question.There is no way for this problem.I realized my mistake.

Comment: Don't publish it on the Internet

Comment: 1) dig deep hole 2) put templates/css in hole 3) cover up hole 4) don't tell anyone where the hole was.

Comment: This is legit question and the answer is to obfuscate (which is commonly done by minification). The question is not too broad either.

Comment: While we may not agree with the question, it is a valid question (even though the answer is "it's not possible'). It would be nice to leave this up somewhere to mark the future repeats daily as Duplicate.

Comment: @Mamad yes they are joking with you. Just take what is useful to you. You can't prevent copying, but you can minify. try searching for minification of css and javascript files.

Comment: And welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say but all client-side code can be copied.

Your best bet is to stop publishing your site online.

**Obfuscate**

However, there are tools that help you obfuscate code. Here's one.

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/

http://htmlobfuscator.com/

**Minify**

On the other hand, most techniques employ that minify your code.

Here's two links:

http://cssminifier.com/

http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Comment: Obfuscating is pointless as well. Anyone who might copy the code can very easily de-obfuscate it. Or if using the CSS/JS code in its entirety is fine for them, there is no need to de-obfuscate anything.

Comment: Well you are right. The idea is to make it harder for the copier or at least if it's a very less experienced coder, then it might just make them loose motivation. But you're right, all client code will be eventually copiable.